# How to separate input field values in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, state

I have a list of inputs that are generated based on the number of items in an array:

```
const itemInputs = items.map(
  item => <Input key={item} value={itemInput} onChange={event => this.updateItem(event)} />,
);
```

Here is what my updateItem function looks like:

```
  updateItem(event) {
    this.setState({
      itemInput: event.target.value,
    });
  }
```

So if there are two items in my array, then two input fields will be generated, like so:
[image]

But when I enter a value for the first input field, that same value appears in the second input field, like so:

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening? I want each input field to retain its own value.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do that

```js
const items = ['firstName', 'lastName'];

const itemInputs = items.map(
  name => <Input key={name} name={name} value={this.state[name]} onChange={event => this.updateItem(name, event)} />,
);

updateItem = (name, event) => {
  this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I assume you are putting all the inputs in one component. And component can have only 1 state.

In other words, you are changing the value of `itemInput`, and it effects all inputs because ypu declared that their value would be `itemInput` of the same component of all.

What you can do is make a new component for input, and call it instead.
That way you will have state for every single input.

Hope that helps.
Good luck

Comment: I see. Well you are still pass those custom component the value on a single component. Which is 1 state.